# Nginx change document root directory

Tags: nginx

I'm using the Windows setup file from [Nginx For Windows](http://kevinworthington.com/nginx-for-windows/)

But It doesn't allow to change the install location, so it defaults to `C:\nginx` Is there a way to update the config file to change the root directory to `D:\blabla`?

Sample code from `nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-p` parameter when you start nginx:

```
nginx -p "D:\blabla"
```

Answer (score 2):

root d:/path/whereever;
will work without issues, but do use a proper windows version like the Butterfly or Caterpillar release and not those other crippled versions.

even a root '//192.168.2.5/mount/webdrive';
will work!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know howit was two years ago but with an current Version (1.13.9) you only need to set the root of your Server

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   D:\blabla;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   D:\blabla;
    }
}
```